# Reduce running time of calculation

Tags: excel, vba, reduce, calculation

I appreciate your reply

I'm using vba program.

mother board , cpu and graphic of my computer are B85M D2V , i5 4690 and gtx 750ti.

I'd like to reduce running time of calculation

I have plan to upgrade  i7 4690 or 6700 and mother board(i don't know what excatly to choose)

I wonder that how does it reduce when cpu upgrade to i7 4690 or 6700 ?
for example
when i5 4690   running time is 10 seconds
after i7 6700 or 4690  running time is 7 seconds

Maybe
if you know that, could you give me reply?

Comment: Whilst increasing the speed of your computer (and adding more memory) should increase the speed of any application, it is also dependent on what the program actually does. As such, this question is not suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expensive processors tend to calcuate quicker (obviously). Unfortunately there is no simple equation like "the i5 4690 is always x times faster than the i7 6700". This depends on the interaction between the hardware and the vba program. This depends on processor architecture & microarchitecture, cache management and many other hardware-driven parameters. Also, your program may has bottle-necks that limit the speed-increase of e.g. multi-thread processing.

Therefore, it is even possible that a more expensive processor (or one with a higher clock speed [Ghz]) is slower in calculating certain programs than an older, cheaper and slower processor (sounds paradox at first glance).

In general, there are thousand of benchmarks out there where you can compare certain processors. This can be used as a rough indicator for the average speed differences between certain processors.